# Javascript: Searching substring pattern and returning found string

Tags: javascript

I have a string composed by several fields. Two of which will always vary in length. I could simply use substring if all fields have fixed lengths.

Sample:

> 48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123

The fields are divided like this:

> 480 | 01 | **MCAbastillas** | 2200800046300017 | 100518 | 110555 | **130000** | 123

The bolded fields are the fields that varies in length. They represent a name and a amount, respectively. I already posted this question but I mistakenly tagged it with Java. I tried to interpret the provided answers into Javascript but being no expert in it, I spent all day producing no results :(

Comment: The not bolded strings will be always the same?

Comment: So do you want to split the first string into the components you've given or do you just want to get the **bold** items you've listed from the string

Comment: The will vary in value but the length will always be the same

Comment: Very little information to go on. Can you confirm that the 6th character is always the start of a random length of _letters_ until another _digit_ is reached?

Comment: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes first argument as a regex and second argument as a function where arguments are according to your regex match groups an example is listed below 
---
`function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
}
var newString = 'abc12345#$*%'.replace(/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
console.log(newString);  // abc - 12345 - #$*%`

Comment: @NickParsons the end goal is for me to have 8 Strings that contains the values of all the fields

Comment: @Uzi what are the allowed characters for the bold parts ?

Comment: @Tigger yes that is correct. all the fields that are not in bold style will always have the same length. only the bold styled fields will have random lengths

Comment: @Apolo the first bold styled field will always be alphabetical while the second one will always be numeric (always whole number. it will never have a decimal point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expression to capture the groups

```js
const regex = /^(.{3})(.{2})(\D+)(.{16})(.{6})(.{6})(\d+)(.{3})$/
const str = '48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123'
const values = str.match(regex)
console.log(values)
```

Comment: I think this is the more accurate solution

Comment: I just have to ignore the first element of the array since it returns the original string followed by the separated set. Thanks. This works for me.

Comment: Yes, the first element is the string that matches the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = '48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123';
// match parts with regex
var match = input.match(/^(.{3})(.{2})([a-zA-Z]+)(.{16})(.{6})(.{6})(\d+)(.{3})$/);
// remove first element (full matching input)
match.shift();
// build output
var output = match.join(' | ');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = [
  '48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123',
  '48001MCAbasti2200800046300017100518110555130000123',
  '48001MCAbastillasXYZ2200800046300017100518110555130000123',
  '48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000999123',
  '48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130123',
  '48001MCAbastillasXYZ2200800046300017100518110555130000999123',
  '48001MCAbasti220080004630001710051811055513123'
]

const p = /(?<name>\D+)(\d{28})(?<amount>\d+)(\d{3}$)/

console.log (test.map (s => s.match (p).groups))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complex version that breaks all the parts based on known values. The regex answer is the way to go.

```js
var r1 = "48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123";
var r2 = "48001RANDOM220080004630001710051811055512345123";

function extract(str) {
    var i = 5,max = str.length;
    var parts = [], cut1, cut2 = (max - 3);
    for(;i<max;i++) {
        if (! isNaN(parseInt(str[i]))) {
            cut1 = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    parts.push(str.substr(0,3));
    parts.push(str.substr(3,2));
    parts.push(str.substr(5,(cut1 - 5)));
    parts.push(str.substr(cut1,16));
    parts.push(str.substr((cut1 + 16),6));
    parts.push(str.substr((cut1 + 16 + 6),6));
    parts.push(str.substr((cut1 + 16 + 12),(cut2 - (cut1 + 16 + 12))));
    parts.push(str.substr(cut2,3));      
    return parts;
}

console.log(extract(r1));
console.log(extract(r2));
```